# Differentiable function on $(a,b)$ satisfying $f’(x)+f(x)^2 +1 \geq 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Prove that if $f$ is differentiable function on $(a,b)$ and if $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = + \infty$, $\lim_{x \to b^-} f(x)  = - \infty$, and $f’(x) + f(x)^2 + 1 \geq 0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$, then $b-a \geq \pi$.

My intuition is to compare the function $f$ with $-\tan x$ because $(-\tan (x))’ + \tan^2 (x) + 1 = -\sec^2 x +\sec^2 x=0$. But, I’m not sure how to start the proof.

Comment: What does "if $f$ is a differential equation" mean? Maybe you mean, "if $f$ is a differentiable function"? Please edit the question so it makes sense.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for clarifying it. I accidentally typed “equation”.

Comment: *differentiable*, not *differential*. It might help if you find the general solution to $f'+f^2+1=0$

Comment: One thing to do is define $g(x)  = \arctan f(x) $ and use the chain rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
-\pi &= \lim_{u\to -\infty} \arctan (u)-\lim_{t\to \infty} \arctan (t)\\
&= \lim_{x\to b^{-}} \arctan(f(x)) - \lim_{s\to a^+} \arctan (f(s))\\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \arctan(f(b-\epsilon)) - \arctan(f(a+\epsilon))\\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int^{b-\epsilon}_{a + \epsilon} \frac{f'(x)}{1+f(x)^2}\mathrm d x\\
&\ge \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int^{b-\epsilon}_{a + \epsilon} (-1) \mathrm d x\\
&= -(b-a)
\end{align}

So $$\pi \le b-a$$